# Is it posible to create an interface having a property with a subgroup of other property in the same object?

Tags: typescript, types, interface

Is it posible to create an interface or type in Typescript, having one of the properties typed as subgroup of keys of other property in the same object?

For example, I have this base types:

```
interface Node {
   id: string;
   // ...other irrelevant properties
}

interface Connection {
  fromNode: string;
  toNode: string;
  // ...other irrelevant properties.
}
```

Now I have an interface for a graph defined like:

```
interface Graph {
  nodes: Record<string, Node>
  connections: Record<string, Connection>
  // other irrelevant properties
}
```

This a sample of a real object:

```
const aGrapgh: Graph = {
   nodes: {
       "nodeA": {id: "nodeA"}
       "nodeB": {id: "nodeB"}
   }
   connections: {
      "nodeA": {fromNode: "nodeA", toNode: "nodeB"}
   }
}
```

Problem here, is that `nodes` and `conections`are typed as a Record with a generic `string` by key. Is there any chance to type it in a way that TS complains if I use `nodeC` on `connections`, because it's not an existing key on `nodes`?

`nodeA` it's just a sample key. On real code, those Ids are `uuid` generated on execution time. I don't want to specify the keys, just to make TS understand they are related. Something like

```
interface Graph {
   nodes: Record<string, Node>,
   connections: {
      [key in Graph['nodes']?: Connection
   }
}
```

Comment: "On real code, those Ids are uuid generated on execution time." Can you explain how you expect the compiler to understand whether two of these are the same or different from each other if they are not known until runtime? Probably this is impossible, since whatever function is making the uuids can't spit out unique *types* for each call (we'd need something like [ms/TS#37469](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37469)) But still, for this to be a [mre] you'd need to show code that gets these uuids and the typings, so that we can explore possibilities. Could you [edit] to do that?

Comment: Hmm, that edit didn't show the code that gets the uuids. If you write `"nodeA"` in your example then you'll get answers about string literal types, which you said you don't want.  Instead, you should make it be more representative of what you're actually doing... which presumably looks like "get some uuids from XXX code and then use them in a `Graph` with YYY being accepted and ZZZ being rejected", where you should fill out XXX, YYY, and ZZZ for us.

Answer (score 1):

What your after is a [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types)

```js
interface Graph {
  nodes: Record<'nodeA' | 'nodeB', Node>
  connections: Record<'nodeA' | 'nodeB', Connection>
  // other irrelevant properties
}
```

or

```js
type NodeType = 'nodeA' | 'nodeB';

interface Graph {
  nodes: Record<NodeType, Node>
  connections: Record<NodeType, Connection>
  // other irrelevant properties
}
```

Which is the same but without the repetition.

Comment: On my real code, `nodeA` and `nodeB` are guids generated on execution time. I'll add it on the descripcion to make it clear

Answer (score 1):

You can make the entire graph generic, an pass in a string literal union type to restrict the node IDs that can be used. This will not only restrict your `Record` keys, but also the `id` properties of your `Node` objects, and the `fromNode` and `toNode` properties of your `Connection` objects:

```
interface Node<T extends string> {
   id: T;
}

interface Connection<T extends string> {
  fromNode: T;
  toNode: T;
}

interface Graph<T extends string> {
  nodes: Record<T, Node<T>>
  connections: Partial<Record<T, Connection<T>>>
}

const graph: Graph<'nodeA' | 'nodeB'> = {
   nodes: {
       "nodeA": {id: "nodeA"},
       "nodeB": {id: "nodeB"}
   },
   connections: {
      "nodeA": {fromNode: "nodeA", toNode: "nodeB"}, // OK
      "nodeB": {fromNode: "nodeB", toNode: "nodeC"}, // Error
   }
}
```

<sup>[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOIDkD2ATCAeAFWQgA9IRsBnZSsKUAcwD5kBvAKGS+GwC5kCAbnYBfdu1CRYiFAGFMIEBARhgCwsTIQK1WvRDM2nZDCiYAtllz8hxsJisQbwsRPDR4SNFDgAHABYapORUNHSMLBxcIDgQlPwASsqYUNiEADRojoRMTMYICkoqaiDxyAAKcFCqcAA2eEkFqRnI8orKquoEuXmuBaVgyAw+AfyoI4EA5DG4AIKTyAA+yNOxAEKTLAC8RlzIM3H8UXt7AEQHs6dHPPznsZci6cYnyHe4a1dsN68HH2J7j2e-SKnVKR2eZwun1YpgsjluUMy9nhP3Wp0eyAA9JjkAB5ADSEK4bwgHyOsMssQRaKRDipqNwsnRmWxyAAolAzFBnmIREA) (Renamed `Node` to `GNode` to prevent clash with built-in `Node` type)</sup>

Comment: Same problem as the other solution from Liam. On my real code, nodeA and nodeB are guids generated on execution time. I'll add it on the descripcion to make it clear. But I guess from both answers it's not posible, because both are based on same idea.